# Reuse fetched data in PHP and MySQL with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

I'm writing an accounting system with PHP and MySQL and using PDO for working with database. In the payment page, I must have 2 drop down lists from defined accounts.
At the first, I've used a simple query to fetch all records for accounts.

```
$sql = "SELECT id,title FROM tbl_accounts WHERE uid = ? ORDER BY title";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($uid));
```

I have put fetched rows in a drop down list and everything was ok.

```
<select name="account_id2" class="medium" id="account_id2">
    <option value="null">---</option>
    <?php
    while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
        echo '<option value="'.$r['id'].'">'.$r['title'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

But when I wanted to make second drop down list using fetched records, nothing have been shown. So I thought I had to create another query for it. I did it and second one made correctly.
But my question is: Can not we use fetched data more than 1 time ? If I needed 3rd drop down, I had to write another query?

Comment: Provide the code you use to loop over the fetched rows? Is it `foreach`, `while`?

Comment: Can you post the code that fetches the results and uses them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your conditional loop, you may need to reset the array pointer using [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php).

#### Update:

To reset a result set you can use [`data_seek()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) or built a separate array as noted in the other answers.

Comment: what do I have to put here? `reset($r)` ?

Comment: I have to put it before `while()` loop ? or after fetching rows?

Comment: It depends, generally you should put it before your next loop. I encourage you to read the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Save the fetched results to an array using `$r = $q->fetchAll()` then loop through `$r` instead of fetching while you're looping.

Answer (score 1):

Why not save the data to an array the first time you use it, so you don't have to bother your Database again for the same data.